# Eureka client can not register with Eureka server

Tags: docker-compose, server, client, registration, netflix-eureka

since a while, I am facing this problem. Following the docs, I created eureka server (configure the application.properties as follows and included in pom.xml spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server) and a microservice as eureka client (configure the application.properties as follows and included in pom.xml spring-cloud-starter-netflix-client) and it worked fine.

When I dockerize the system and added application-docker.properties for the special additions (follows) the registration never happened.

Server application.properties:

##Eureka properties

server.port=8761

spring.application.name=discoveryserver

spring.application.user.name=eureka

spring.application.user.password=password

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

Client application.properties:

##eureka.client.region=default

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

Client application-docker.properties:

server.port=8181

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@discoveryserver:8761/eureka/web

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

There is no application-docker.properties for server

What is the reason client never accepted to be registered? Its logs stat that it tries to register but the reply is 404

I tried to add (eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true) but didn't work so I took it out. Also, I tried to change the url in the application-docker.properties of the client and use localhost (which shouldn't) but it didn't work.